# JavaScript basic variable returning a value entered by user

Tags: javascript

I'd like to try to return a value entered by the user. For example, I'm asking for his/her name, then he/she would input it in the textbox. The value of the textbox should be displayed. How will I do this?

In Java this is how I did it:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String uname;

System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
uname = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("Hello " + uname);
```

Comment: this: <script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
var uname = prompt("Please enter your name: "); 
alert("Hello " + uname);
</script>

Comment: But I don't know how to do it without using prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried so far? It sounds like you'd like to use a JavaScript prompt... here's a crude example and here some info you should read... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.prompt

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to demonstrate....</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<input type="text" id="demo"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
var x;

var name=prompt("Please enter your name","Bob Mould"); // note that you can put a default value...

if (name!=null){
  x="Hello " + name + "!";
  document.getElementById("demo").value=x;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
```

Update **

from the comment below "*No, what I want to do is get the name of the user from this `<input type="text" name="uname" /`> and then when the button is clicked it should be displayed in another textbox.*" which is different from the original question this is what you want however your original question was misleading...

Try this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button</p>

<input type="text" id="uname" />

<input type="text" id="demo" />

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
  if(document.getElementById("uname").value.length > 0){
    document.getElementById("demo").value = document.getElementById("uname").value;
  }else{
    alert("please enter a value");
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, what I want to do is get the name of the user from this <input type="text" name="uname" /> and then when the button is clicked it should be displayed in another textbox.

Comment: Okay, from your original question you didn't really ask for this... however I will update the answer...

Comment: I will try this one. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `prompt` method:

```
var name = window.prompt('Please enter your name:');
```

Then user would see a popup and enter his/her name in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" onclick="returnValue(this)" />

function returnValue(element)
{
  alert(this.value);
}
```

Simple but works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get input from user with prompt use this,

```
var name = prompt("Please enter your name");
alert(name)
```

variable 'name' will return the input given by user